# How do I determine the number of elements in an array reference?

Tags: perl, json

Here is the situation I am facing...

```
$perl_scalar = decode_json( encode ('utf8',$line));
```

decode_json returns a reference. I am sure this is an array. How do I find the size of $perl_scalar?? As per Perl documentation, arrays are referenced using @name.  Is there a workaround?

This reference consist of an array of hashes. I would like to get the number of hashes.

If I do length($perl_scalar), I get some number which does not match the number of elements in array.

Comment: Just for a straight array, the search engines are fond of *[Find size of an array in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406807)*.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That would be:

```
scalar(@{$perl_scalar});
```

You can get more information from [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

You can copy your referenced array to a normal one like this:

```
my @array = @{$perl_scalar};
```

But before that you should check whether the `$perl_scalar` is really referencing an array, with [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html):

```
if (ref($perl_scalar) eq "ARRAY") {
  my @array = @{$perl_scalar};
  # ...
}
```

The [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) method cannot be used to calculate length of arrays. It's for getting the length of the strings.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the last index of the array to calculate the number of elements in the array.

```
my $length = $#{$perl_scalar} + 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$num_of_hashes = @{$perl_scalar};
```

Since you're assigning to a scalar, the dereferenced array is evaluated in a scalar context to the number of elements.

If you need to force scalar context then do as [KARASZI says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885794/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-elements-in-an-array-reference/5885838#5885838) and use the `scalar` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the entire structure with Data::Dumper:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $perl_scalar;
```

Data::Dumper is a standard module that is installed with Perl.  For a complete list of all the standard pragmatics and modules, see `perldoc perlmodlib`.