# Finding out the number of elements in an array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, count

I am trying to write a Perl script that will traverse an XML file and find all entries named 'className'.

I am using a the [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) library which is turning out to be very poorly named.

The library appears to represents sequences of similarly named elements as an array.

I am trying to iterate over the elements in the list, using a basic indexed loop. So I'm trying to find out how many elements are in the array:

```
    } elsif("ARRAY" eq ref(@_[0])) {
        my $list = @_[0];
        print "scalar($list): " . scalar($list) . "\n";
        print "\$#list: " . $#list . "\n";
        print "\n";
    }
```

Here is the output of my code:

```
scalar(ARRAY(0x600845398)): ARRAY(0x600845398)
$#list: -1
```

I've found references online to using the scalar function and the strange `$#` notation, but neither is giving me a number that makes any sense.

Comment: `scalar($list)` -- `$list` is already a scalar. You need to use @ to dereference $list and then use `scalar @$list` to get the length.

Comment: Also, `@_[0]` is taking a one-element array slice from `@_`.  Better written as the single item `$_[0]`.

Comment: Also, `$list` is a bad name for a variable that contains an array (or, as in this case, an array reference). It just encourages people to believe that arrays and lists are the same thing.

Comment: I'm starting to get the feeling that the user of perl in new code should be discouraged. :) Where can I learn the meaning and necessity of all the different prefix hieroglyphics?

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How do I determine the number of elements in an array reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885794/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-elements-in-an-array-reference)*

Comment: Just for a straight array, the search engines are fond of *[Find size of an array in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406807)*.

Answer (score 4):

`$list` is an array ref, not an array. Try `scalar @{$list}`. Also - try `XML::Twig` as a way of XML parsing.

Answer (score 2):

The use of [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) in new code is discouraged.

This is from the advice of the [module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE) itself:

> #### STATUS OF THIS MODULE
>
> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, `XML::LibXML` is highly recommended.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options and the arbitrary ways in which these options interact - often with unexpected results.
>
> Patches with bug fixes and documentation fixes are welcome, but new features are unlikely to be added.

For new code, I would recommend using either [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

Both of these modules utilize XPaths for locating and modifying nodes, which is a lot more powerful than trying to translate  an XML document into a perl data structure like `XML::Simple` does.

The following is an example of how to count the number of nodes named `className` in a fake XML document:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml( IO => \*DATA );

my @className = $xml->findnodes('//className');

print "Count is " . @className . "\n";

__DATA__`
<root>
    <foo>
        <className id="one" />
        <className id="two" />
        <className id="three" />
    </foo>
    <bar>
        <className id="four" />
        <className id="five" />
        <className id="six" />
    </bar>
    <baz>
        <biz>
            <className id="seven" />
            <className id="eight" />
            <className id="nine" />
        </biz>
    </baz>
</root>
```

Outputs:

```
Count is 9
```

Comment: Does findnodes only return the number of nodes that match the xpath? I can't find anything in the docs about actually traversing the document, or getting attributes from nodes. Just a cryptic reference to "In scalar context, the function will return a XML::LibXML::NamedNodeMap object." which doesn't have any documentation.