# perl+json getting size of an array

Tags: json, perl

I'm reading a json file in perl and having trouble using the results.

I want to know how many views are present in the json file.
there should be 2

```
my $data = decode_json($json);
print Dumper($data);

my @tmp=$data->{'views'};
my $nviews=scalar @tmp;
print "nviews : $nviews\n";
```

gives me

```
$VAR1 = {
    'views' => [
        {
            'key' => 0,
            'value' => {
                'ptr_wrapper' => {
                     'data' => {
                         'width'    => 776,
                         'height'   => 1024,
                         'id_view'  => 0,
                         'filename' => '000118800_15821618907.jpg',
                         'id_pose'  => 0,
                         'id_intrinsic' => 13,
                         'local_path' => '/'
                     },
                     'id' => 2147483649
                 }
             }
        },
        {
             'key'   => 1,
             'value' => {
                 'ptr_wrapper' => {
                      'data' => {
                          'id_pose'      => 1,
                          'id_intrinsic' => 11,
                          'filename'     =>  '000132800_22050281512.jpg',
                          'id_view'      => 1,
                          'local_path'   => '/',
                          'width'        => 850,
                          'height'       => 1024
                      },
                      'id' => 2147483650
                  }
             }
         }
    ]
};
nviews : 1
```

thanks in advance for any help.luc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the number of elements in an array reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885794/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-elements-in-an-array-reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $views = $data->{views};
my $nbViews = scalar @$views;
```

`$data->{views}` is a reference to an array, not an array. Store the reference, and dereference it when needed.

Alternatively:

```
my @views = @{$data->{views}};
my $nbViews = scalar @views;
```

As pointed out by [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021376/perljson-getting-size-of-an-array/35021445?noredirect=1#comment57772655_35021445), note that this alternative makes a **copy** of the original array (potentially using a lot of memory). In some cases that may be what you actually want to do (if you need to modify it while leaving the original one intact, though note this would not be a deep copy), but most often (especially if you just want to count the items or iterate over them), you probably don't want to do that and just stick to keeping a **reference** (as in the first code snippet above).

Comment: What about `my $nbViews = scalar @{$data->{views}}` wouldn't that work as well?

Comment: @Borodin Point taken.

Comment: @dev-null: That `scalar` is unnecessary, so I would choose `my $nbViews = @{ $data->{views} }` if I didn't need to access the array elsewhere, but in practice that's very unlikely

Comment: @jcaron: I think you should make it clear that your *Alternatively* makes a duplicate of the array, which is often unnecessary and may be devastating if `@$data` is very large. It is certainly not something to do if you just need a count of elements in the array

Answer (score 4):

When you write this

```
my $data = decode_json($json);

my @tmp = $data->{'views'};
```

you are creating a Perl array with a single element `$tmp[0]` that is *identical* to `$data->{'views'}`.

Your `$data->{'views'}` is spot on, so you have correctly understood how to access the `views` element of the hash referred to by your `$data` variable, and as long as the hash key `views` looks like a Perl identifier you can forget the quotes around it

But the values of Perl hashes and arrays are always scalar, so you must *dereference* them if you need to access the array, and the same applies to any substructures that you need to access

If you are dealing with complex data structures, it is usually best to keep a temporary scalar variable that tracks where you are within the structure. For instance, I would write

```
my $views = $data->{views};
```

Now I have a simple *array reference* to code with. I can dereference it to an array with `@$views`, and I can access its elements with `$views->[0]` etc.

Here's a rewrite of your own code that does what I have described. I have also used [`Data::Dump`](http://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) to reformat the data that you show. It is generally far more concise and readable than the output from `Data::Dumper`, but it isn't a core module so you will probably have to install it

I pull out `$value->{ptr_wrapper}` as a lexical variable `$wrapper`, and in turn `$wrapper->{data}` as lexical variable `$data`. The rest of the code becomes so much simpler, as I could otherwise be writing stuff like

```
say $data->{views}[0]{value}{ptr_wrapper}{data}{filename}
```

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $data = {
  views => [
    {
      key => 0,
      value => {
        ptr_wrapper => {
          data => {
            filename     => "000118800_15821618907.jpg",
            height       => 1024,
            id_intrinsic => 13,
            id_pose      => 0,
            id_view      => 0,
            local_path   => "/",
            width        => 776,
          },
          id => 2147483649,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      key => 1,
      value => {
        ptr_wrapper => {
          data => {
            filename     => "000132800_22050281512.jpg",
            height       => 1024,
            id_intrinsic => 11,
            id_pose      => 1,
            id_view      => 1,
            local_path   => "/",
            width        => 850,
          },
          id => 2147483650,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};

my $views = $data->{views};
my $nviews = scalar @$views;

print "nviews : $nviews\n\n";

for my $view ( @$views ) {

    my $key     = $view->{key};
    my $value   = $view->{value};
    my $wrapper = $value->{ptr_wrapper};
    my $data    = $wrapper->{data};

    say "key      = $key";
    say "ID       = $wrapper->{id}";
    say "filename = $data->{filename}";
    say "height   = $data->{height}";
    say "width    = $data->{width}";
    print "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
nviews : 2

key      = 0
ID       = 2147483649
filename = 000118800_15821618907.jpg
height   = 1024
width    = 776

key      = 1
ID       = 2147483650
filename = 000132800_22050281512.jpg
height   = 1024
width    = 850
```

Comment: perfect.just a note , 
 
I wouldn't use my $data = $wrapper->{data}; as it overwrites the original $data and I need it later.

Comment: @lulutreizequinze: It doesn't “overwrite” the original `$data`. It introduces a new `$data` that disappears at the end of the enclosing block -- the `for` loop. After that the old `$data` and its original value are accessible once again. You shouldn't need the outermost value of `$data` inside the loop -- that is the point of *scoping*